# XSOM vs Apache XmlSchema

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd, xsom

I wanted a library which can be used to introspect an XSD. Basically parse it and give an object representation so that I can get the types, names, annotaions,namespace etc. So I came across mainly two of the libraries:
[java.net XML Schema Object Model (XSOM)](http://xsom.java.net/)
and
[Apache commons XMLSchema](http://ws.apache.org/commons/XmlSchema/index.html)

I felt XSOM is better, but it seems to be having a different CDDL license. So will I be able to use XSOM in a commercial project which I cant make open source? Any of you aware of any better such libraries which will have LGPL type of license?

Comment: xsom is now part of https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxb-ri/tree/master/jaxb-ri/xsom, artifact https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:xsom

Answer (score 0):

I've used Apache commons XMLSchema and it works well.

But loving or hating a library that merely expose a view of an underlying structure is mostly a subjective thing.

Regarding license, XSOM itself seems to be released under a mixture of GPL and simil-GPL licenses. If you want to go on the safe side go with Apache and relax.

Putting my Apache hat on, if you feel that Apache commons XMLSchema can be improved, please join the project mailing list, let us hear your ideas, submit patches, and help us make it a better library.